Join table with column next value above or below threshold in SQL
I have a table with a column price. I'd like to join this column the value above a threshold or below depending on what's hit first.
For instance:
If my prices are [10, 11, 15, 18, 15, 10, 7] and my threshold is 20%
Then for 10, +20% = 12, -20% = 7. But 15 is above 12 before it hits 7.
for 11, 15 is above 13.2.
for 18, 10 is below 14.4
So in the end, I'd like a table like this
[
[10,15],
[11,15],
[15,18],
[18,10],
[15,10],
[10,7]
]

7 has nothing so is not included.
Any idea how I could do that in SQL please? My db is a sqlite
Or if it's simpler just return 1 if it reaches the above threshold first and -1 if below .
And i have an ID column that is integer for ordering.

Careful! The rows in SQL tables don't have an inherent order. In the lingo of collections of data, they are bags of rows, not lists of rows. So you need to define what column gives you an order that allows you to specify first.

Good call. I have an ID column in the table that is ordered
